# Stop drop-down going offscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following for displaying a custom table. It works nicely as is, but I'm having some trouble with drop-downs in the table headers.

```css
.as-table {
  position: relative;
}
.as-table-head {
  background-color: rgb(30, 36, 42);
  width: 100%;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th {
  color: white;
  font: bold 13px/15px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 30px;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(30, 36, 42);
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
  border-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
  border-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th:hover .as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: visible;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container {
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container:focus {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container:focus .as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: visible;
}
.as-table-head-dropdown-arrow:focus {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button > span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 13px/15px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 30px;
}
.as-table-dropdown {
  background-color: #E9EAEB;
  right: auto !important;
  top: 28px;
  border: 0;
}
.as-table-dropdown > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(214, 215, 217);
  color: #333;
}
.as-table-head .valigned:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.as-table > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 3px;
  font: normal 13px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgb(214, 215, 217);
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:focus td {
  background-color: rgb(124, 152, 171);
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:focus {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped as-table">
  <thead class="as-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th class="valigned">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxHead" class="as-table-checkbox-head">
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Connected</span>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Mac Address</span>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Enabled</span>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>IP Address</span>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>CName</span>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>
        <img src="~/Content/img/connecting" />
      </td>
      <td>00:8f:5e:aa:bb:00</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>192.168.1.1</td>
      <td>23:23:23:23:23:2323:23:23:23:23:2323:23:23:23:23:23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see how the drop-downs appear below the table headers, but the last one goes off-screen. I would like it to appear in the image below, the menu moving in from the left edge of the screen, but have had no luck in finding out how to do it:

[image: snippet of dropdown]

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

I have the following which works but it *feels* wrong..

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx2z6m6k/3/embedded/result/)

I added this class to the last `<th>` element:

```
.as-last-th {
    right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything to achieve "the menu moving in from the left edge of the screen"? Please let us know what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: Howdy, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

To do it the "proper" way. try

```
.as-table-dropdown:last-child {
    right: 0 !important;
}
```

This will make sure that the last element that has the class name of `.as-table-dropdown` will have the properties given. I don't see anything wrong with the execution of the code. But i believe you may be able to clean up the CSS and use some JavaScript in the process to make the bars more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to achieve this. I used bootstrap classes (as opposed to custom classes with `!important` which can get complicated and difficult to maintain), and I must admit that I'm not 100% sure I've used them as they are intended.

1. I changed to bootstrap 3.1.0, which has [depreciated "pull-right"](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-dropdown-pull-right) due to a [reported issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10370).
2. I removed the `right` declaration from `.as-table-dropdown`.
3. I used `.navbar-right` to float `.btn-group` elements to the right.
4. Then I applied `.dropdown-menu-left` or `.dropdown-menu-right` to align the drop-downs left or right as applicable.

```css
.as-table {
  position: relative;
}
.as-table-head {
  background-color: rgb(30, 36, 42);
  width: 100%;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th {
  color: white;
  font: bold 13px/15px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 30px;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(30, 36, 42);
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
  border-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button:hover {
  background-color: #333e48;
  border-color: #333e48;
}
.as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th:hover .as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: visible;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container {
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container:focus {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}
.as-table-dropdown-container:focus .as-table-head-dropdown-arrow {
  visibility: visible;
}
.as-table-head-dropdown-arrow:focus {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th > div > button > span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 13px/15px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 30px;
}
.as-table-dropdown {
  background-color: #E9EAEB;
  /*right: auto !important;*/
  top: 28px;
  border: 0;
}
.as-table-dropdown > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(214, 215, 217);
  color: #333;
}
.as-table-head .valigned:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.as-table > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 3px;
  font: normal 13px"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgb(214, 215, 217);
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:focus td {
  background-color: rgb(124, 152, 171);
}
.as-table > tbody > tr:focus {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped as-table">
  <thead class="as-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th class="valigned">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxHead" class="as-table-checkbox-head">
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Connected</span>

        <div class="btn-group navbar-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Mac Address</span>

        <div class="btn-group navbar-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle  dropdown-menu-right as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>Enabled</span>

        <div class="btn-group navbar-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>IP Address</span>

        <div class="btn-group navbar-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="valigned"> <span>CName</span>

        <div class="btn-group navbar-right">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle as-table-dropdown-container" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="http://uniqsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/small-black-down-arrow.png">
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right as-table-dropdown">
            <li><a href="">Sort Ascending</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sort Descending</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>
        <img src="~/Content/img/connecting" />
      </td>
      <td>00:8f:5e:aa:bb:00</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>192.168.1.1</td>
      <td>23:23:23:23:23:2323:23:23:23:23:2323:23:23:23:23:23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```